# How to read JSON value pair in a table

Tags: arrays, json

I have a JSON file like this below

```
 {
    "timestamp": 1546387198,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
      "AED": 3.673105,
      "AFN": 75.615,
      "ALL": 107.726773 
      }
  }
```

I want to read the above JSON in the follow form of table.

> **Timestamp | Base | CurrencyTo | FXRate**
>
> 1546387198 | USD | AED | 3.673105
>
> 1546387198 | USD | AFN | 75.615
>
> 1546387198 | USD | ALL | 107.726773

How should I read the rates object as a set of values?
I am working with Azure Data Factory. Please suggest how can I retrieve such form of data from Json.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You have timestamp & base as straightforward. Just need to loop rates, where key will print AED/AFN/ALL & value will print 3.6731/75.615/107.72.
Though it will be better if you can share what you have already tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of creating the table:

```js
let jso = {
    "timestamp": 1546387198,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
      "AED": 3.673105,
      "AFN": 75.615,
      "ALL": 107.726773 
      }
  }



  function tableCreate() {
  let tbl = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  let values = Object.values(jso.rates);
  let keys = Object.keys(jso.rates)

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 let tr = document.createElement('tr');
 let td1 = document.createElement('td');
 let td2 = document.createElement('td');
 let td3 = document.createElement('td');
 let td4 = document.createElement('td');

 td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jso.timestamp));
 td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jso.base));
 td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(keys[i]));
 td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(values[i]));

 tr.appendChild(td1)
 tr.appendChild(td2)
 tr.appendChild(td3)
 tr.appendChild(td4)
   tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }
    }



tableCreate();
```

```css
th, td {
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Timestamp</th>
    <th>Base</th>
    <th>CurrencyTo</th>
    <th>FXRate</th>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
```